# Prove that for $k>1$ $a_n$ is a perfect square

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recursion, square-numbers

I'm having problems with this exercise.
Let $k > 1$ be an integer. We define $(a_n)_{n \in \Bbb N_0}$ as:
$$a_0 = 1$$ $$a_1 = 1$$ $$a_{n+2} = (k^2-2)a_{n+1}-a_n-2(k-2)$$
Prove that $\forall n \in \Bbb N_0, a_n$ is a perfect square.

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. I want to prove that $a_n=(a+b)^2$ in some way. I was going to attempt with induction, $P(0)$ and $P(1)$ are true, $P(2)=(k-1)^2$... but how should I pick $P(n)$ and $P(n+1)$. Or should I try other method?

I've also tried finding the roots so I could have the closed formula for the sequence but I've ended up with a rather disappointing looking expression: $\frac{(k^2-2) \pm \sqrt{k^4-4k^2-8k+16}}{2}$

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried explicitly computing $P(3)$, $P(4)$, etc. to see if you can find a pattern?

Comment: THat *screams* induction to me.  An the set up is right there.  All you have to do is hit it with a paddle.  Prove if $(k^2-2)a_{n+1} - a_n - 2(k - 2)=m^2$ is a perfect square then $((k+1)^2 - 2)(k^-2)a_{n+1} - a_n - 2(k - 2) - a_{n+1} - 2(k-1)= ((k+1)^2 - 2)m^2 -j^2- 2k - 2$ is also a perfect  square.

Comment: @fleablood, be interesting to see a really easy treatment of this.

Comment: Gio, where did you get this problem?

Comment: @Will it's from an algebra course of the university of buenos aires. It's the number 24 http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/materias/1ercuat2016/algebra_I/3-1ro2016.pdf (it's in spanish). I will provide more context in future posts thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just one of those things, given $b_0=1, b_1 = 1,$ and
$$  b_{n+2} = k \, b_{n+1} - b_n, $$ then
$$ a_n = b_n^2. $$

The key step is
$$ b_{n+2} b_n - b_{n+1}^2 = k-2 $$
Let us show how that fits in: we say $a_n = b_n^2.$ We know $b_{n+2} + b_n = k b_{n+1.}$ Square both sides, this gives
$$ b_{n+2}^2 + a_n + 2 b_{n+2}b_n = k^2 a_{n+1}, $$
$$ b_{n+2}^2 + a_n  = k^2 a_{n+1} -  2 b_{n+2}b_n, $$
$$ b_{n+2}^2 + a_n  = k^2 a_{n+1} -  2 b_{n+2}b_n +  2 b_{n+2}b_n - 2 b_{n+1}^2 - 2 k + 4, $$
$$ b_{n+2}^2 + a_n  = k^2 a_{n+1} - 2 b_{n+1}^2 - 2 k + 4, $$
$$ b_{n+2}^2 + a_n  = k^2 a_{n+1} - 2 a_{n+1} - 2 k + 4, $$
$$ b_{n+2}^2 + a_n  = (k^2 -2) a_{n+1}  - 2 k + 4, $$
$$  b_{n+2}^2   =  a_{n+2}. $$

In turn, $ b_{n+2} b_n - b_{n+1}^2 = k-2 $ comes from a standard quadratic forms construction. We consider the quadratic form $f(x,y) = x^2 - kxy + y^2.$ Its Hessian matrix is
$$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
2 & -k \\
-k & 2
\end{array}
\right)
$$

We define a matrix $A$ (for "automorphism") as
$$
A = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
k & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right).
$$ 
The word automorphism means
$$  A^T H A = H. $$
In turn, from the observation that
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
b_{n+2}  \\
b_{n+1} 
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
k & -1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
b_{n+1} \\
b_n
\end{array}
\right)
$$
we find 
$$ b_{n+2}^2 - k b_{n+2} b_{n+1} + b_{n+1}^2 =  b_{n+1}^2 - k b_{n+1} b_{n} + b_{n}^2, $$ so that
$$ b_{n+1}^2 - k b_{n+1} b_{n} + b_{n}^2 $$ is independent of $n$ and constant.
From $b_1$ and $b_0$ we find
$$ b_{n+1}^2 - k b_{n+1} b_{n} + b_{n}^2 = 2-k. $$
Finally
$$b_{n+2} b_n - b_{n+1}^2 = (k b_{n+1} - b_n) b_n - b_{n+1}^2 = - b_{n+1}^2 + k b_{n+1} b_n - b_n^2 = -(2-k) = k-2  $$

I asked the OP for the source of the problem, it turns out the part about defining $b_n$ was the  hint given; exercise 24. The exercise (review?) set pdf is at [PDF](http://cms.dm.uba.ar/academico/materias/1ercuat2016/algebra_I/3-1ro2016.pdf)

[image]